# aws: How to start a ecs task invoked by lambda and send back the public ip

Tags: amazon-ecs

I have a requirement, where every user will interact with a fresh server and close it when he done with the work.

So i am thinking of

API Gateway --> Lambda --> invoke ECS task (here i am running a flask api server)

now when i call the api gateway, i want to get the ECS task public ip and also ecs task id.

using that public ip i can start interacting with the server.

and when i done with the work i will call flask api/lambda endpoint which will terminate the ecs task.